# Possible to give view and download access to a document (.pdf) without revealing the full URL?

Tags: security, pdf, download

**Is it possible to give a user access to a .pdf file - meaning to allow them to download it for example by clicking a button - without revealing the full URL in the process?**

so say I have a file at `www.mydomain.com/content/pdf/valuable_ebook.pdf`

I want to give a link which triggers a download, but only shows valuable_ebook.pdf , rather than the full path (which could be shared, leading to unpaid downloads).

I do consider to create a copy of the file and temporarily place it in a location which is specific to a certain download link. But I wonder if there is an easier way to do this.

As far as viewing goes, I was thinking to make like an iframe, which doesn't give the full URL away... So that even "view source" will not make it easy to determine the full URL from above. Any way to achieve this?

Of course there might be java or flash applications that allow the viewing of pdfs (speaking of which - does anyone have a good example for one?).

Would it be possible for such an app to have a download feature, which does not reveal the full URL? How would this communicate with the browser?

Or is it possible to restrict access to the URL from above maybe through .htaccess and put some server sided logic in place to grant access only if you are a registered/paid member or something?

I was just wondering if there were any remote possibilities to allow downloading/viewing a file without giving away the file location.

Thankful for any ideas or insight on how the browser has to communicate with the server to start a download...

PS: I realize it's easy to share a digital item once you have downloaded it, but I'm trying to set up at least a few hurdles to filter out any leaking.

**PARTIALLY ANSWERED:**
I actually found a good solution for **DOWNLOADING** the file without giving the source URL away (at least not anything that I would know of - so a big chunk of the users probably wont know it).

```
// FILE www.mydomain.com/download.php

if($user_has_access_to_download == TRUE)
{
  $file = 'content/pdf/valuable_ebook.pdf';
  header('Content-Type: application/x-octet-stream');
  //header('Content-type: application/pdf');
    //wondering which is better?                
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="your_ebook.pdf"');
  header("Content-Length: " . filesize($file));
  // header("Connection: close"); 

  readfile($file);
}
```

Following a link to `www.mydomain.com/download.php` will now trigger a download, not without revealing the source file.

Now I just need to find something that helps with viewing (rather than `<iframe src="www.mydomain.com/content/pdf/valuable_ebook.pdf">` ) Because that poses 2 problems: 
1. source URL can easily be seen and shared
2. Browsers give a "save as" button - but I would rather have them go through my `download.php` to keep track and such...

Possibly I'm gonna have to try and find some sort of a Java app to view pdfs...

Comment: What server-side web language are you using? I can give you a nice example/answer for your chosen platform.

Comment: @BenPoulson I am working with PHP. Can't wait to hear your "nice example" :-D

Answer (score 1):

I would handle this by adding some sort of parameter to the url so that your new link would look something like `www.mydomain.com/content/pdf/valuable_ebook.pdf?code=abc123` where `abc123` is a new random value for each person you give the link out to.  Obviously, make it much longer than 6 characters.

You then store all of the codes in a database.  From here you have a couple of options.  You could only give them the option to download the PDF a specified number of times.  When the code is used more times than that, perhaps they could contact you to download it more times, but you easily be able to stop anyone that shares the link a bunch of places.

Comment: Sure a good idea, thanks! How would I run a script which interacts with the `code=abc1234` value when directly opening a pdf? I mean if I go to a pdf file, my browser will use the adobe plugin to view the pdf, but no server sided code is being executed (at least not to my knowledge)... Can I somehow specify (perhaps through .htacces) what should be done when a certain file type is targeted, before actually allowing access to the file?

Answer (score 0):

**PARTIAL ANSWER:**
I found a good solution for **DOWNLOADING** the file without giving the source URL away. Posting it here for completeness.

```
// FILE www.mydomain.com/download.php

if($user_has_access_to_download == TRUE)
{
  $file = 'content/pdf/valuable_ebook.pdf';
  header('Content-Type: application/x-octet-stream');
  //header('Content-type: application/pdf');
    //wondering which is better?                
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="your_ebook.pdf"');
  header("Content-Length: " . filesize($file));
  // header("Connection: close"); 

  readfile($file);
}
```

Following a link to `www.mydomain.com/download.php` will now trigger a download, not without revealing the source file.

*Let me know if there is a super easy trick to finding the source URL to this method, or if you have any other thoughts!*